# Why header file sees source file's includes?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

Header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <uWS/uWS.h>

typedef __uint32_t ClientID;
typedef __uint16_t Port;

class ClientServer
{
public:
    ClientServer();
    ClientServer(const ClientServer&) = delete;
    ClientServer& operator=(const ClientServer&) = delete;
    ~ClientServer();

    bool run(const std::string& host, Port port);
    bool disconnect();

    bool isConnected(ClientID id);
    bool send(std::initializer_list<ClientID> idList, const std::wstring& message);
};
```

Source file:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

#include "client_server.h"

ClientServer::ClientServer()
{
}
```

As you can see the header file uses some std classes like `std::string`, `std::initializer_list`, the types from `<stdint.h>`. And this code compiles, why the header file sees the imported headers in the source?

Comment: `#include` means exactly that - compile the .cpp file as if the text of the included file was copy/pasted into the .cpp file replacing the #include directive.

Comment: Unrelated: you shouldn't use `__int` or `__uint` types yourself; those are internal to the implementation. You should use `uint32_t` etc. instead, which are actually defined by `cstdint` (which you should also prefer to `stdint.h`).

Comment: Do you even need to include <uWS/uWS.h> in this header?

Comment: Expanding on @DanielH 's comment. In general avoid anything with a double underscore anywhere in it. They are not part of any public interface and may change without notice. Never make an identifier with a double underscore in it either. Double underscore has been reserved for use in the deep-dark of the library implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Because this source file is included *after* other library headers. Try moving it to the top and you'll get a compiler error.

That's what `#include` does - it simply copies the header file contents and pastes it to the `#include` location.

Comment: I made it like that:

`#include "client_server.h"`

`#include <stdint.h>`
`#include <string>`
`#include <initializer_list>`

but it still compiles?

Comment: @AsenValchev What does `<uWS/uWS.h>` include?

Comment: Okay, that was. Obviously it was including those headers.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor directive `#include` is just a textual substitution (a "copy-paste") of "header" file (or any other file) into the file that contains the `#include` directive. In the end, when everything is included, you end up with a flat linear text file. There's no surprise in the fact that everything included later (below) can see everything included earlier (above).

Answer (score 2):

In C++, header files work by taking the text of the header file and putting it into the source file at the location of the `#include`.* In this case, before including `"client_server.h"`, you include `<stdint.h>`, `<string>`, and `<initializer_list>`. Therefore the compiler has seen all of these before your header file.

Best practice is usually to include your own unit's header file *before* any others, so that you are sure you include everything you need from the header file and don't accidentally cause this issue for anybody else using the header.

---

* Technically, I'm fairly sure it only includes the tokens of the header file, not actual source inclusion, but in most cases there's no difference.